# SSRS barcode font embedding to PDF

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-pdf, reportserver, font-embedding

I have a problem embedding a barcode font to a report. Exporting to PDF, it doesn't show the barcode. It only shows the numbers.

I have the font installed on the server. I reboot the server after installing the font, and it doesn't work.

But, i try on different versions of SQL Server and i get:

1. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard. Doesn't Work.
2. SQL Server 2012 Web Edition. Doesn't Work.
3. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Data Center. IT WORKS.

Is there something to do in the versions where it is not working?

Any idea would be great!